# Noun Subject Question: Comma or Not?

Tags: commas, subjects

According to an answer key, there should be a comma before "called". However, I thought it was part of the subject and in a subject, there should not be commas. Can anyone explain why there is a comma?

> These single-celled **survivors, called** extremophiles, don't merely endure environments too serve for other life forms.

Thanks

Comment: There is a comma because you are not distinguishing the single-celled survivors in question from others by giving their name. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition#Restrictive_versus_non-restrictive

Comment: So would this require commas: I have a lot of friends and one of them, Alex, is a tennis player.

Comment: And basically, if it is a proper noun, it will most likely go between commas, correct?

Comment: The phrase _called extremophiles_ is reduced from the nonrestrictive relative clause _which are called extremophiles_. Since it's nonrestrictive, it has to be separated by comma intonation at both ends. The relative clause modifies _survivors_, so it is part of the subject, but it's not the word _called_ that modifies it -- it's the whole reduced clause.

Comment: @G.B No, proper nouns can go either way: *That man, Johannathan, runs* vs *My friend Johannathan runs.*

Comment: @Scrooble, I was mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**These single-celled survivors, called extremophiles, don't merely endure environments too serve for other life forms.**

-called extremophiles is closed in by commas because the commas act as an **appositive**

**Appositive**s are words that add information to a **noun** or **noun phrase** that precede them.  They are always enclosed by commas.

In your example the added  information = what the single celled survivors are called.

Here are a few more examples.

1. Liverpool**, my home town,** is a wonderful place.
2. My friend**, called Fred,** is not very clever.
3. English**, my favourite subject,** is very challenging.

Appositives function to add more information and to make our language more interesting.

I hope that helps you.

Source: Advanced Grammar Course Manual.  BC Ministry of Education, Canada.

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma because it is used as parenthesis. You are separating a subordinate clause - a part of the sentence that doesn't make sense on its own. This is why you have two commas in the sentence. If you remove the section within the commas, the rest of the sentence still makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I agree commas are warranted before and after *called extremophiles* but must call attention to typo: "too serve" I believe should be "too severe."